# connector/j for mysql-installer-community-5.6.10.1

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-6.9

i am new for mysql and java so i don't know how to `Install connector/j` and also which `version of connector/j`  for mysql-installer-community-5.6.10.1. ?

Answer (score 0):

driver version should not be a problem. you can use latest version `(5.1.24)` of driver. it will work.

connector need not install, just keep the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar` in you project and add its path to `classpath`.